# setInterval, animating multiple images, stopping setInterval

Tags: javascript, animation, setinterval

I need to create some animation using DHTML/Javascript and I am struggling to get anything I do to work. My parameters are it must use the setInterval function, a user defined function and 8 jpg files. There must also be a way of stopping the animation.

If someone could get me pointed in the right direction I would be very happy. I have not been able to find suitable information on how to do this so far and I am still fairly new to Javascript. Thanks.

Sorry for not posting code earlier. It was such a mess I didn't want to embarrass myself. Here's what I have. It's not working.

```
var slideShow = ['images/pic0.jpg','images/pic1.jpg','images/pic2.jpg','images/pic3.jpg','images/pic4.jpg','images/pic5.jpg','images/pic6.jpg','images/pic7.jpg'];
picO = new Array();
for(i=0; i < slideShow.length; i++) {
picO[i] = new Image();
picO[i].src = slideShow[i];
}
var curPic = -1;
function changeImage(){
curPic = (++curPic > slideShow.length-1)? 0 : curPic;
imgO.src = picO[curPic].src;
setInterval(changeImage,100);
}
window.onload=function(){
imgO = document.getElementById("imgAnim");
changeImage();
}

var t=setTimeout(function(){alert("Welcome to my animated page")},3000)
```

The other thing it needs to do is pop up an alert box 3 seconds after the animation starts. It's doing that but it's popping up EVERY 3 seconds, which is not what I want.

Thanks for your help so far. I've done pretty well with my Javascript work lately but this one is just something I'm not that familiar with.

Comment: code is always good to clarify the question. can you please share?

Comment: are you saying you want a slideshow?

Comment: I recently wrote an answer to a question that may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017649/javascript-settimeout-setinterval/17017717#17017717

Comment: It's not DHTML, that was all that nonstandard stuff that Microsoft had in IE4 and 5. It is called HTML5

Comment: you parameters are questionable... if you need to animate images, you don't want `setInterval` at all, you want `requestAnimationFrame`. Have a read-over of http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/05/requestAnimationFrame-API-now-with-sub-millisecond-precision for more details. Also note that usually SO is for asking questions when you get stuck programming, not for "I haven't start yet, how do I write the following program".

Answer (score 1):

To the using of setInterval and stopping the animation

```
var animation = setInterval(yourAnimation,500); // run yourAnimation every 500ms
clearInterval(animation); // stop animation
```

To the animation

```
var slideShow = ["img1.jpg","img2.jpg", ... ,"img8.jpg"];
var counter = 0;
function yourAnimation() {someImage.src = slideShow[++counter%slideShow.length];}
```